# Given a polynomial ring in 4 variables then....

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, maximal-and-prime-ideals

MULTIPLE CHOICE CORRECT ANSWER

Consider the ideal $I := (ux, uy, vx, uv)$ in the polynomial ring $\mathbb{Q}[u, v, x, y]$, where

$u, v, x, y$ are indeterminates. Choose the correct statement(s) from below:

$i):-$ Every prime ideal containing $I$ contains the ideal $(x, y)$;

$ii):-$ Every prime ideal containing $I$ contains the ideal $(x, y)$ or the ideal $(u, 
v)$;

$iii):-$ Every maximal ideal containing $I$ contains the ideal $(u, v)$;

$iv):-$ Every maximal ideal containing $I$ contains the ideal $(u, v, x, y)$.

ATTEMPT

Let P be the Prime-Ideal containing  $I := (ux, uy, vx, uv)$ $I \subseteq P$ $\implies ux,vx,vy \in P$

If $x\notin I$ then since $ux,vx \in P$ we have $u,v \in P \implies (u,v) \in P$

on the other hand

If $u\notin I$ then since $uy,ux \in P$ we have $x,y \in P \implies (x,y) \in P$

Is my partial solution correct?

I had done with Options i) and ii).

What about iii),iv)?

Comment: (i) is false, since $I\subseteq\langle u,v\rangle.$ Similarly,
(ii) is false as $I\subseteq \langle u,x\rangle$

Comment: @learning_math ii) not false I think.

Comment: Is the ideal in question really $(ux, uy, vx, uv)$, or is it supposed to be $(ux, uy, vx, \color{red}{vy})$?  You say that $vy \in P$, but that doesn't seem to follow from your definition of $I$.

Comment: @Quasicoherent Sir the question is correct.I matched 3 times.I had mistaken in my attempt.I corrected that.

Comment: $\langle u-1,v,x,y\rangle$ is a maximal ideal such that $I\subseteq \langle u-1,v,x,y\rangle$ and $\langle u,v\rangle\not\subset \langle u-1,v,x,y\rangle$ and $\langle u,v,x,y\rangle\not\subset\langle u-1,v,x,y\rangle$. This means that both (iii) and (iv) are false.

Comment: A primary decomposition of $I$ (computed in Macaulay2) is $I = (u,v) \cap (u,x) \cap (v,x,y)$. You can use this to analyse each of i) through iv).

Comment: On the other hand, $(u,v) \cap (x,y) = (ux,uy,vx,vy)$ and this ideal satisfies (ii).

Comment: @TrevorGunn, how does observation $(u,v) \cap (x,y) = (ux,uy,vx,vy)$ say that '(iii) Every maximal ideal containing $I$ contains the ideal $(u,v)$', and '(iv) Every maximal ideal containing I contains the ideal $(u,v,x,y)$' are false? (I am taking $I=(ux, uy, vx, vy)$ and not the one that OP posted).

Comment: @Silent $V(I)$ is a union of two planes and maximal ideals containing $I$ correspond to points of $V(I)$. Just take a point on the $V(x,y)$ plane not contained in the $V(u,v)$ plane. E.g. $(x,y,u,v-1)$.

Comment: @TrevorGunn, Wow! Can I know which book to read to find this kind of relation between ideals to planes? It was totally new and unexpected to me! I want to know more ..

Comment: @Silent The correspondence between ideals and vanishing loci is the subject of algebraic geometry. [J. S. Milne's notes](https://www.jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/ag.html) get to what I'm talking about around page 40. [Mile's Reid's book](https://homepages.warwick.ac.uk/staff/Miles.Reid/MA4A5/UAG.pdf) around page 60 (he has an extra chapter on elliptic curves that Milne doesn't). You'll want to start reading from the beginning of course.

Comment: Thank you very much, sir! @TrevorGunn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is incorrect because all the four options are false.

(i) is false because $I\subseteq \langle u,v\rangle$.

(ii) is false because $I\subseteq \langle u,x\rangle$.

For (iii) and (iv)....

Notice that $\langle u-1,v,x,y\rangle$ is a maximal ideal. For a proof see Magdiragdag's [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2440222/trying-to-prove-that-langle-y-x2-z-x3-rangle-is-prime-in-kx-y-z).

Notice also that $I\subseteq\langle u-1,v,x,y\rangle$.

(iii) is false because $\langle u,v\rangle\not\subset\langle u-1,v,x,y\rangle$.

(iv) is false as $\langle u,v,x,y\rangle\not\subset\langle u-1,v,x,y\rangle$.

To prove $\langle u,v\rangle$ is prime..

Consider the evaluation map $f:\mathbb{Q}[u,v,x,y]\rightarrow \mathbb{Q}[z_1,z_2]$ defined as
$$f(u)=f(v)=0 \text{ and } f(x)=z_1 \text{ and } f(y)=z_2$$
Then $$\frac{\mathbb{Q}[u,v,x,y]}{\langle u,v\rangle}\cong \mathbb{Q}[z_1,z_2]$$
To prove that $\ker (f)=\langle u,v\rangle$ you may want to look at Magdiragdag's answer.

To prove $\langle u-1,v,x,y\rangle$ is maximal...

Consider the evaluation map $f:\mathbb{Q}[u,v,x,y]\rightarrow \mathbb{Q}[u,v,x,y]$
$$f(u)=1, \text{ } f(v)=v, \text{ }  f(x)=x,  \text{ }  f(y)=y$$
Then $\ker(f)=\langle u-1,v,x,y\rangle$. (For explanation see Magdiragdag's answer.)
Then we it follows
$$\frac{\mathbb{Q}[u,v,x,y]}{\langle u-1,v,x,y\rangle}\cong \mathbb{Q}$$

Comment: how do I prove that (u,v),(u,x) are prime ideals and (u-1,v,x,y) is a maximal ideal.I can't relate Magdiragdag'answer with this.